# How can I make Impromptu jquery pause current-function execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, impromptu

How can I make Impromptu jquery pause current-function execution like Javascript's native "alert" function ?
http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Currently script execution continues in the background while my dialog is showing !

Or is it impossible with that library ? Recommends ?

UPDATE :
I want to pause script execution because my code is called by an onchange event of a select element and **I want the user to decide whether to save his work or not** (through the dialog)

But the problem is that after the dialog is shown, the onchange function keeps running and starts loading the new content in my tinymce editor (because the selection changed.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to halt script execution.  The alert dialog is a special case.

Comment: What is the reason you want to stop script execution? There may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

They have an example on their github page. I bet a simple copy and paste of their code would work.

https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Impromptu/blob/master/demo.html